# Html->link in home page to another controller action

Tags: hyperlink, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to link a controller action in my home page. this is what i wrote:

```
<?php $this->Html->link(__('Assign', array('plugin' => 'full_calendar',
                                           'controller' => 'events',
                                           'action' => 'assign',
                                            $events['Event']['id']
                                          )
                          )
                       ); ?>
```

but when the home page renders, the button label is /pages/Assign, and the url is pointing to this path: www.mysite.com/pages/Assing

How can I escape from pages controller and link to another controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the parenthesis wrong :)

```
<?php $this->Html->link(__('Assign'), array('plugin' => 'full_calendar',
                                       'controller' => 'events',
                                       'action' => 'assign',
                                        $events['Event']['id']
                                      )
                   ); ?>
```

The `__()` function should only correspond to the "Assign" string.

Beside that tiny mistake (always happens, so be sure to check for parenthesis mishaps before panicking), the way you're calling the function is ok and it should redirect you correctly.

Comment: LOL :) that's embarassing!

Comment: Happens to everyone more than once :)